# How to notify an abnormal client termination to server?

Tags: c, signals, freebsd, kqueue, berkeley-sockets

As the Title already says im looking for a way, to get notified when a client closes his Session unnormal.

I'm using the freeBSD OS.
The server is running with Xamount threads (depending on CPUcore amount). So I'm not forking, and there isn't a own process for each client.

That's why sending an deathpackage all time_t seconds, to recive a SIGPIPE isn't an option for me.
But i need to remove left clients from the kqueue, because otherwise after too many accept()'s my code will obviously run into memory troubles.

Is there a way, I can check without high performance loose per client, they are connected or not?

Or any event-notification, that would trigger if this happens? Or maybe is there a way of letting a programm send any signal to a port, even in abnormal termination case, before the Client process will exite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [kqueue man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2), `kevent()` should create an event when the socket has shutdown. From the description of th filter `EVFILT_READ`:

> EVFILT_READ
>
> Takes a descriptor as the identifier, and returns whenever there is data available to read.  The behavior of the filter is slightly different depending on the descriptor type.
>
> Sockets
>
> Sockets which have previously been passed to listen() return when there is an incoming connection pending. data contains the size of the listen backlog.
>
> Other socket descriptors return when there is data to be read, subject to the SO_RCVLOWAT value of the socket buffer.   This may be overridden with a per-filter low water mark at the time the filter is added by setting the NOTE_LOWAT flag in fflags, and specifying the new low water mark in data.  On return, data contains the number of bytes of protocol data available to read.
>
> **If the read direction of the socket has shutdown, then the filter also sets EV_EOF in flags, and returns the socket error (if any) in fflags.**  It is possible for EOF to be returned (indicating the connection is gone) while there is still data pending in the socket
>               buffer.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: that answer misses the question, because it's not about using kqueue. But if someone else finds the question by the title, it may be helpful anyway ...*

I've often seen the following behaviour: if a client dies, and the server does a `select()` on the client's socket descriptor, `select()` returns with return code > 0 and `FD_ISSET( fd )` will be true for that descriptor. But when you now try to read form the socket, `read()` (or `recv()`) return ERROR.

For a 'normal' connection using that to detect a client's death works fine for us, but there seems to be a different behaviour when the socket connection is tunneled but we haven't yet managed to figure that out completely.

Comment: yeah, but the point is, kqueue has the behaviour of replacing select() so im not using a select in any case ;)

Comment: ok sorry, and let me guess, `kevent()` doesn't behave like `select()` in that case?

Comment: yip, kevent() is kind of eventlistener which returns me a list of all sockets that trigger a special event i.e. something is ready to write or read. so if there is a socket, that got closed by client, kevent() just won't threw any events of that socket anymore. Thats also why i guess, handling a timer for each socket would be a way with big loose of performance. (Because i had for each socket to increment a own time value, what absolutly would miss the behaviour of kqueue() in my view)

Comment: I've read [the manuel](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) and the description for `EVFILT_READ` sounds a bit like there is an event when the socket has shutdown. But i guess you have already tried that.

Comment: Yeah, i read that man page like 20 times before i was able to write my own kqueue server but the 2 sentence about the EOF flag i never noticed. I'm gonna check it in the evening it about it works or not. You should wirte a new answer, because your probbably right but the above is absolutly not whats answering my question. ;)